# How to Slow Down Crouch Funtion UE4

Tags: c++, camera, interpolation, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I am making a shooter game in unreal 4.25 with c++. I am working on the input and animations right now. I like how the crouch animation looks and the speed, but the camera appears at the crouch height right away and doesn't seem to interpolate their. I am just using the `crouch()` and `uncrouch()` funtions in Unreal. I found where the funtion is and all it seems to to do is set a bool `bWantsToCrouch` to true or false. I looked for all references of this bool and its only being changed not used. So I'm pretty sure it's in blueprints somewhere and is used in the camera comp. I have searched the player and camera comp for something to slow this down and found nothing, thanks for any help you can give me.